# 3 textboxes, 1 button, on button click put text in the textbox where the cursor is

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cursor

I have 3 textboxes and a button, what I need to do is that on the button click I want text to appear in which ever textbox the cursor is located.

I can do it for one textbox but for 3 different I need 3 different buttons.

Can you plz help me do it using just one button???
Plz help..

This is what I have accomplished for 1 textbox:

function insertAtCaret(areaId, embedctrl) {

```
        var text = document.getElementById(embedctrl).value;
        if (text != "-1") {
            var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
            var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
            var strPos = 0;
            var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
                "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
            if (br == "ie") {
                txtarea.focus();
                var range = document.selection.createRange();
                range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
                strPos = range.text.length;
            }
            else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

            var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
            var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
            txtarea.value = front + text + back;
            strPos = strPos + text.length;
            if (br == "ie") {
                txtarea.focus();
                var range = document.selection.createRange();
                range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
                range.moveStart('character', strPos);
                range.moveEnd('character', 0);
                range.select();
            }
            else if (br == "ff") {
                txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
                txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
                txtarea.focus();
            }
            txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
        }
    }
```

In the above eg, the dropdown's(embedctrl) selectedvalue gets inserted at cursor position in a textbox.

## Part 2:

I tried the following using a dropdownlist to insert text in the textboxes but it doesnt work. Any insights so as to why???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var selectedTextBox;
           $("input[type='text']").on("focusin", function () {
               debugger;
               selectedTextBox = this;
           });
           $("#ddlEmbedDBField").on("change", function () {
               debugger;
               var value = document.getElementById('<%=ddlEmbedDBField.ClientID%>').value;
               if (document.getElementById('<%=ddlEmbedDBField.ClientID%>').value != "0")
               {
                   $(selectedTextBox).val(value);
               }              

           });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: can you show please some example, the one you have made so far... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without using jQuery:

```js
var lastclick;

  function LastClicked(elem){
   lastclick=elem;
  }

  function putText(area){
   lastclick.value=area.value;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="LastClicked(this)"/>
<input type="text" onblur="LastClicked(this)"/>
<input type="text" onblur="LastClicked(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="putText(document.getElementById('mytext'))"/>
<textarea id="mytext" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
```

You keep track of the last element focused.

Comment: Thanks Fabio !!! A little modification and it suited my need very well. Cheers !!

Comment: Glad to have been helpful :) @JacksonLopes

Answer (score 3):

You could keep track of the selected text box whenever focus changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedTextBox;
        $("input[type='text']").on("focusin", function() { 
            selectedTextBox = this;
        });
        $('#ddl').on("change",function(){
            var selectedVal = this.value;
            $(selectedTextBox).val(selectedVal);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, if you have more than just the three textboxes you'd have to be more specific in your selector.

Comment: Thanks DoctorMick...But my requirements have changed a bit. The button has been replaced with a dropdownlist. Can you plz review the Part 2 of my question for details. Thanks a ton anyway !!!

Comment: One of two things could be causing the problem.  1 - either your id is not #ddlEmberDBField or 2 - it is #ddlEmberDBField which probably means this won't work: var value = document.getElementById('<%=ddlEmbedDBField.ClientID%>').value;  instead of using document.getElementById within the change callback you should just use the this keyword.  I've edited my answer to work with a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

HTML Code

```
<input type='text' id='my-textbox1' />
<input type='text' id='my-textbox2' />
<input type='text' id='my-textbox3' /><br/>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='Click' />
```

JS Code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var textSelected;
        $("input[type='text']").on("focusout", function() { 
            textSelected = this;

        });
        $("#btn").on("click", function() { 
            $(textSelected).val("Hello");
        });
    });
```

Here is working Example
[Click](http://jsfiddle.net/4ctvnLof/3/)

Comment: That doesn't work (at least not in Chrome), the text box has lost focus because of the button click.

Answer (score 0):

check this code your purpose will be achieved. Hope it helps.

```js
var inputFocusedId;
function loadValue(){
    $('#'+inputFocusedId).val('abc');
}

function focussed(obj){
    inputFocusedId = $(obj).attr('id');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" onfocus="focussed(this);" />
<input type="text" id="input2" onfocus="focussed(this);" />
<input type="text" id="input3" onfocus="focussed(this);" />


<button  onclick="loadValue()" >Submit</button>
```